# How does installing ca-certificates-(mono/java) affect the certificate store?

Tags: security, certificates

I installed the `mono-complete` package and was very surprised to see these lines on the installation log:

```
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20190110ubuntu1.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
```

and a few lines below:

```
127 new root certificates were added to your trust store.
```

It seems that is caused by the installation of `ca-certificates-mono`. An `apt-cache search ca-certificate` also indicate that there is a similar package for Java (`ca-certificates-java`).

Does this affect the system trusted root certificate store? If no, I would expect Mono and Java to use their own internal certificate store. Then why does it call `/etc/ca-certificates/update.d`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not *completely* fluent in the behavior of ca-certificates or of the packages you stated, but I did dig a bit into the packages..

`ca-certificates-{mono|java}` install different ca-certificates update hooks.  `/etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore` for Java and `/etc/ca-certificates/update.d/mono-keystore` for Mono.

The Java package repackages all of the existing CA certificates trusted by `ca-certificates` (including added, trusted certs from manual installation, etc.) into a JKS (Java KeyStore) format for use by Java applications.  It doesn't have any configuration or files added which would generate new certificates, however the 'updates' would be the certs being bundled into JKS format.

The Mono package actually calls Mono's program, `certsync.exe`:

```
exec /usr/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS /usr/lib/mono/4.5/cert-sync.exe "$@"
```

This seems to be Mono's mechanism to sync the system `ca-certificates` store with Mono's keystore, which I think is handled separately from the system `ca-certificates` store because it's got a `.exe` format and Windows compat - it might be being rebundled into a Windows compatible cert store for Mono programs.

Regardless, after dissecting the update scripts and what files these packages seem to install, neither package will alter what certs are actually on your system - but all certs being updated and added to a cert store when the new update hooks are applied will happen if those keystores haven't been updated.